# Error while using javax.crypto API in cassandra UDF

Tags: cassandra

I have written a cassandra UDF using java code to encrypt data. For this I have used the `javax.crypto.Cipher` and `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec`.

I am unable to create the UDF as I am getting the following error:

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Java source compilation failed:
>   Line 1: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec cannot be resolved to a type
>   Line 1: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec cannot be resolved to a type
>   Line 1: javax.crypto.Cipher cannot be resolved to a type
>   Line 1: javax.crypto.Cipher cannot be resolved to a type
>   Line 1: javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE cannot be resolved to a type

```
    create function encrypt("val" text)
    returns null on null input 
    returns text
    language java as
    '
    String strData="";
    javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new 
    javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec("abc".getBytes(),"Blowfish");
    javax.crypto.Cipher cipher=javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,skeyspec);
    byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(val.getBytes());
    strData=new String(encrypted);
    return strData;
    ';
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to verify, that your code is well indented. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.

Comment: This is the first time I am posting a question. Please through some light on as how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your code snippet is not very well indented. It has some leading spaces which are unnecessary and also no indentions of blocks. You may add them.

Comment: I hope the code is well indented now. thanks in advance

Comment: Also removed the unnecessary spaces.

Comment: I have also added the javax.crypto.jar in the $CASSANDRA_HOME/lib folder